# no me carga un estilo css dentro de una etiqueta <template>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

veran yo tengo mi template asi. mediante stripe conecto con fetch y accedo a una lista de datos como productos y precios y los genero dentro de ese template. hasta ahi todo bien **el problema es que cuando intento agregar un css no lo carga dentro del template**

```
<section id="Payment" class="Payments"></section>
        <template id="Website-static">
            <figure id="FH" class="Web">
                <img>
                <figcaption class="fig-caption-Name"></figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig-caption-Price"></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </template>
```

el ejemplo que que puse aqui que le aplica un border después de hacer click a las cartas es lo que quiero hacer dentro del template pero no me agarra... **¿me preguntaba el porque no agarra?**

```js
$('.test').on('click',function(){
    $('.test').removeClass('show-border');
    $(this).addClass('show-border');
});
```

```css
.test{
background-color: red;
width:100px;
height:40px;
margin:12px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.show-border{border:5px solid green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> lo que intento es algo asi</h1> 

<div class="test"> </div>

<div class="test"> </div>
```

Comment: si eso es verdad ya actualize el post. pero en el código original lo tengo con las comillas

Comment: cierto ya arregle el ejemplo. y corre perfecto el hacer click y sale el border . pero ahora el problema principal es que  como había mencionado en el post  yo tengo un template **lo puedes ver arriba** bueno entonces cuando intento aplicarle ese ejemplo que puse ella no funciona

Comment: si agregas dinamicamente los elementos tenes que agregarles el on click a cada nuevo elemento, o delegar a un parent que cuando aparezca un elemento con tal clase le agregue la func

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo para que en el futuro quienes vean este post sepan la respuesta

Comment: el buscador no es muy bueno, aquí hay uno que cuelga eventos del `document`https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177391/81450 y aquí uno de fragmentos que se cargan https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/407776/81450 recuerdo haber escrito otros ejemplos pero no les encuentro

Comment: básicamente: al evento lo enganchas a un parent que no desaparece y la definicion va con 3 parametros: eventos, selectores a los que aplica, función

Comment: Gracias por la Respuesta y explicación precisa, ya entendí el porque no estaba funcionando

Comment: otro enfoque es observar cambios en el DOM y aplicar eventos o cosas extra https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206377/81450